# What will happen to production certificate if the creator of the certificate (team admin) is removed from the enterprise account?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, mobile

As a Team Admin I have created the production certificate for client enterprise application. Using this certificate now the enterprise app has gone live. Now I need to remove myself from the client's enterprise account. My question is, will this affect the existing production certificate in anyway?  What will be the outcome? Will this affect the existing enterprise app?

Comment: it wont impact anything into it

Comment: @Shobhakar Tiwari thank you for answer. So "Leave Team" option will do the job without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

It will not impact existing, enterprise signed apps.

1) Team Agent

You can transfer roles to another person to avoid those issues. You can find detailed information in your account under [Transferring Roles](https://developer.apple.com/support/account/).

2) Team Admin

You can simply add another team member as admin. Find details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html).

Regarding the certificate: if you invoked the certificate, it is based on your private key. So you either have to export the certificate (including your private key) from the `Key Chain`application or the new admin has to revoke the certificate to sign future releases.

Comment: thanks for your input. I guess transferring roles is only applicable for team agent. I could not find such option in my account (team admin).

Comment: that means the our developers wont be able use existing production certificate to sign the next release? Im bit confused